How to Log.d messages from another process of the same app?
I need to make a Service that must run in a separate process so that it still run when the MainActivity is closed. And I use android:process=":myprocess" in manifest for that. If I don't insert this in the project manifest and run the app, I can see the massages from the service, but when I start it in another process the messages from Log.d are no longer shown. Is there a way to make it work ?

What is wrong with my question that you voted to close it ?

How are you looking for the messages? If you are using Android Studio's Logcat tool, are you sure that your filters are not causing an issue?

@CommonsWare It's a BeeWare project and it has a tool named briefcase that build and run the app on my phone through USB cable. When it run I see a lot of debuging text on the laptop screen, with all kind of colors, from different sources. And it shows the debuging text from my foreground service too, but only when I set the service to run in the same process as the MainActivity.

Briefcase will only show logs from your app's main process. To see the other process, you could use Android Studio's Logcat view, or the adb logcat command.
However, for your use case I don't think you actually need a separate process. By default, all activities and services will be run in the main process, and that process will continue to exist for as long as at least one of its components is active.
Android's decision about when to shut down a service is determined by other factors which you've already discovered in your other question. I don't think putting it in a separate process will make much difference to that.
Also, adding a second process is a significant complication which is probably more trouble than it's worth. For example, the two processes won't be able to communicate with each other by simple method calls, and will have to use Intents, sockets or bound Service interfaces instead.

And there is no way to make it show logs from other app process ?

Not in Briefcase, but you could also use Android Studio's Logcat view, or the adb logcat command.

Maybe you will add this feature in the next version of BeeWare... :) I cannot use the Android Studio because I want to write the Android app in Python with BeeWare. I tryed the adb logcat too and it outputs a lot of messages even when I do nothing in my app. I cannot understand anything from there...
